# How to get the name of a variable from the DataWeave Playground Input Explorer variable as a String

Tags: dataweave

I'm trying to mimic some DataWeave code from Studio in the DataWeave Playground. There is a variable set in the Input Explorer named myFile.xml. Is there a way to get the variable name and data format as strings "myFile" and "xml", or "application/xml"?

Comment: Hi @Ethan, for the name I'm not sure, but did you try with `myFile.^`? That get's the metadata

Comment: the variable name is actually `myFile.xml` in the view? Are you asking if you don't have the actual name?

Comment: If I try to create an input called `myFile.xml` it creates it as `myFile` with format `XML`. I could not find a way to put a dot in the name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the names of the 'inputs' defined in the Input Explorer. The `vars` object is not defined in DataWeave Playground like in an executing Mule application.

If you defined the variable `myFile` of type XML in the DataWeave Playground's Input Explorer you can use the expression `myFile.^mediaType` you can get the type `"application/xml"`.